# TFS - issue with go online , once worked in offline mode

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, tfs

We are working in Visual Studio with TFS.

We are facing one issue in it. if we work offline for, and then go online, then rather than showing conflicts on files which have been changes, it asks to checkout all files or it will show confilit in all files.

Can any body have idea if this behaviour. How to resolve it??

Comment: It will show conflicts when you try to check in file which u changed when you were offline. Does this answer your question?

Comment: Also how you go offline?

Comment: I select whole solution , and click on `Go Online`.

Comment: but it shows conflict for all files, which i haven't changed in offline mode, even for images and dll :(

Comment: Can you try to go offline? When you go offline close solution and reopen again. Also does your conflicts show any differences

Comment: @AshReva, I had tried to close solution , close visual studio and then open both again. then it do not ask me for TFS credentials and been in offline mode. So i have to do `Go Online` manually, selection whole solution. 

and for all the files , expect in which i had done changes. it do not show me any conflicts. when i compare them all was latest.